# Insertar Columna en un Dataframe dependiendo de otro Dataframe de diferente Tamaño

Tags: python, dataframe

Tengo dos dataframes con los mismos nombres en sus columnas pero diferentes tamaños:

DF1 (10x3)

```
Fecha        Cliente     ID 
---------------------------   
12-03-2020    Prada     AAA   
22-04-2020    Coutine   BBB
02-02-2020    MarioG    CCC
15-11-2020    Sublime   DDD
19-08-2020    Sublime   EEE
23-04-2020    Prada     FFF
30-07-2020    MarioG    GGG
11-10-2020    MarioG    HHH
07-03-2020    Prada     III
06-01-2020    Prada     JJJ
```

DF2 (5x3)

```
Fecha        Cliente     ID 
---------------------------   
17-03-2020    MarioG    CCC   
25-05-2020    Sublime   EEE
04-02-2020    Prada     AAA 
15-10-2020    Sublime   DDD
30-08-2020    Coutine   BBB
```

Lo que necesito es generar una columna en el DF1 llamada "Estatus", que diga "Si" o "So" esta presente el ID del DF2, por ejemplo, el resultado seria:

DF1

```
Fecha        Cliente     ID  Estatus
------------------------------------   
12-03-2020    Prada     AAA     Si
22-04-2020    Coutine   BBB     Si
02-02-2020    MarioG    CCC     Si
15-11-2020    Sublime   DDD     Si
19-08-2020    Sublime   EEE     Si
23-04-2020    Prada     FFF     No
30-07-2020    MarioG    GGG     No
11-10-2020    MarioG    HHH     No
07-03-2020    Prada     III     No
06-01-2020    Prada     JJJ     No
```

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
DF1["Estatus"] = ["Si" if DF1["ID"].values == DF2["ID"].values else "No" for x in  DF1["ID"]]
```

Pero me da error de longitudes o dimensiones de los dataframe.

¿Alguna recomendación para tratar este problema?

Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma correcta y creo que más fácil de hacerlo sería usar el método `isin()` de un *DataFrame* el cual comprueba si un dato se encuentra en un *DataFrame* o en una de sus columnas. la sintaxis es: `df.isin(value)`. Esto nos indica las pociciones en la que se encuentra y muchas veces se utiliza para hacer *filtros* pero nosotros queremos evaluar una sentencia booleana. Si hacemos directamente lo otro nos lanzará un error de ambigüedad `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Para evitar eso y obtener su valor booleano utilizaremos el método `any()`.

```py
df1["status"] = df1.apply(lambda x: "si" if df2["ID"].isin(x).any() else "no",axis=1)
print(df1)
```

El método `apply()` se utiliza para *aplicarle* cualquier cosa, en este caso una función lambda y le decimos que retorne `si` encaso cumpla la condición y `no` en caso no la cumpla. El parámetro `axis` indica que iteraremos en las columnas y `x` (de la función lambda) tomará el valor de cada columna.

**resultado**

|  | Fecha | Cliente | ID | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12-03-2020 | Prada | AAA | si |
| 1 | 22-04-2020 | Coutine | BBB | si |
| 2 | 02-02-2020 | MarioG | CCC | si |
| 3 | 15-11-2020 | Sublime | DDD | si |
| 4 | 19-08-2020 | Sublime | EEE | si |
| 5 | 23-04-2020 | Prada | FFF | no |
| 6 | 30-07-2020 | MarioG | GGG | no |
| 7 | 11-10-2020 | MarioG | HHH | no |
| 8 | 07-03-2020 | Prada | III | no |
| 9 | 06-01-2020 | Prada | JJJ | no |

Comment: Si me funcionó, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción es usar [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`DataFrame.dropna(axis=1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html?highlight=dropna#pandas.DataFrame.dropna) + [`Series.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html?highlight=map#pandas.Series.map).

Hacemos un merge de `df1` y `df2` por la columna `ID`, nota que `df1` está al lado izquierdo del merge. Con `indicator=True` el merge nos trae una nueva columna llamada `_merge`, la cual nos inidica si `ID` está en ambos dataframes (valor `'both'`) o solo en el dataframe izquierdo (valor `'left_only'`). Recordemos que el dataframe del lado izquierdo es `df1`. Ya con esto, solo nos queda renombrar dicha columna por `Estatus` (usando el metodo `rename`) y cambiar los valores `'both'` por `'si'` y `'left_only'` por `'no'`, para esto último es que usamos el metodo `map()`.

```
df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['ID'], suffixes=('', '_y'), indicator=True).dropna(axis=1).rename(columns={'_merge': 'Estatus'})
df1['Estatus'] = df1['Estatus'].map({'both': 'si', 'left_only': 'no'})
print(df1)
```

Salida:

```
       Fecha    Cliente     ID  Estatus
0   12-03-2020  Prada       AAA     si
1   22-04-2020  Coutine     BBB     si
2   02-02-2020  MarioG      CCC     si
3   15-11-2020  Sublime     DDD     si
4   19-08-2020  Sublime     EEE     si
5   23-04-2020  Prada       FFF     no
6   30-07-2020  MarioG      GGG     no
7   11-10-2020  MarioG      HHH     no
8   07-03-2020  Prada       III     no
9   06-01-2020  Prada       JJJ     no
```